# How to bench software on multiple graphic cards with cluster

Tags: testing, graphics, cloud, desktop-application, benchmarking

I would like to bench my software on multiple graphics cards without buying any existing ones!

Do you know any service providers for that?

I wonder if there is something like http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/ for desktops. I guess the game industry might use this kind of service to test their graphics engine...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about http://www.gaikai.com/ they render in the cloud.

Comment: Thank your for the link. I did not find it. However, this is not exactly what i am looking for. gaikai provides streaming whereas my company would like to keep the application as standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Hate do answer your "how do I do this?" question with "don't do that", but...

Don't do that :)

I suspect most of the kind of people who want to test their graphics software on multiple hardware can afford to buy all the multiple hardware, so there isn't much demand for the sort of thing you are asking, particularly not if you want it for free.

If you want to do stuff on the cheap, try:

- Aim low.  Get a $30 card or two and test on those.  This will cover 99% of your potential user base.
- Deal with the major brands.  For desktops, this means ATI and nvidia.  Not many other brands to worry about here, except intel if you want to stretch that far.
- If you are brave enough, publish your benchmarking software on the web somewhere and ask other kind users to test it and submit results.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to follow your advice (but maybe will anyway if no solutions come...). Why? Our GPU base is very large. We have to test cheap and old GPU (S3, Intel) but obviously high-end too. This means looking for old GPU cards. This would take a LOT of time and we are a very small company. We cannot afford wasting time. But let's continue, we spend few hours to buy cards with PCI, AGP, PCIExpress slots. We maybe have to buy corresponding motherboard too... and then switch every hardware by ourselves. Running tests. Meanwhile our team cannot work on the software...